# Redirecting stdin and stdout within idle-python3

Tags: python-idle

I have a Python3 program which I can execute from my terminal by typing:

```
python3 prog.py < inp_file > out_file
```

I would like to execute this program within an Idle shell without any change, but I did not find how to tell Idle which files to use.

Answer (score 2):

The IDLE shell is not a command line terminal.  It mostly imitates the standard interactive Python shell.  You cannot use the terminal-specific syntax with either. But you should be able to do the equivalent with

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('python3 prog.py', stdin=infile, stdout=outfile)
```

The files should be open files, not file names.  Read the [subprocess doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).